# При закрытии доступа в iptables не работает интернет

Tags: linux, iptables

Хочу закрыть доступ к серверу, кроме 3-х портов. Когда применяю правила, в системе перестаёт работать инет. То есть извне я по ssh подключаюсь, а изнутри пинг даже не идёт

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: так самое первое правило говорит "выбрось все пакеты".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С `-P INPUT DROP` по умолчанию будут выбрасываться также и все пакеты, приходящие в ответ на попытку установить исходящее соединение. Дабы избежать сиё недоразумение, их нужно явно разрешить:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Этих трех портов мало. Еще, как минимум, требуется доступ от Вашего сервера к серверам времени (протокол ntp), и DNS.